# C++ calling a class function inside another function

Tags: c++, function, class, function-pointers

I am trying to call an outside function (that takes functions as inputs) inside the class by giving class member functions as it's parameters. My code is as follows:

```
using namespace std;
// This is my external function
double integrate (double a, double b, int steps, double (*func)(double)){
    // code for integration using function pointer
};

Class A
{
    protected:
        vector<double> to_data, from_data;
        int data_size;

    public:
        A (); // constructor

        double calculate_parameter(double t){
            // some class member function that makes use of other class members
        };

        double get_result(double x){
            double sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<data_size;i++){
           // this is basically what causes the error
            sum = sum + integrate(to_data[i],from_data[i],1,calculate_parameter);
        }
 };

}
```

However, it shows me error that the function calculate_parameter cannot be converted. I figured out a way to solve this would be to modify the external function such that it takes a class object as well. Is there a way to do this without instantiating a new class object? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The more general approach is to drop these 1970s function pointers and use technology from this millennium:

```
#include <functional>

double integrate (double a, double b, int steps, std::function<double(double)> f)
{
    // ...
}

class A
{
    double calculate_parameter(double t);

    double get_result(double x)
    {
        using std::placeholders::_1;

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
            sum = sum + integrate(
                to_data[i],
                from_data[i],
                1,
                std::bind(&A::calculate_parameter, this, _1)
            );
        }

        return sum;
    }
};
```

This provides a simple and easy way to bind to essentially any kind of function, and to "bake in" the `this` pointer for member functions to the functor itself, without requiring any magic at the eventual callsite (i.e. within `integrate`, which literally just has to call `f`!).

---

An even more "modern" way to do this is to wrap the call to `calculate_parameter` in a lambda:

```
template <typename Callable>
double integrate (double a, double b, int steps, Callable f)
{
    // ...
}

class A
{
    double calculate_parameter(double t);

    double get_result(double x)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
            sum = sum + integrate(
                to_data[i],
                from_data[i],
                1,
                [this](double x) { return this->calculate_parameter(x); }
            );
        }

        return sum;
    }
};
```

Notice that I've replaced `std::function<double(double)>` with a deduced template argument `Callable`; you don't *have* to do this, but it's conventional not to force a lambda-to-`std::function` conversion when you don't have to. (*Personally* I quite like being able to mandate that `f` will take a `double` and return a `double`, without having to rely on its usage to check this.)

Comment: @nurettin: "Self-gratification"?? What?? Try not to be so rude, thanks.

Comment: quite precise and best answer

Comment: This millenium technology is a lambda, not that archaic bind stuff.

Comment: @Puppy: Yeah, true. Though `std::bind` was added to the language in 2011, which was only three years ago.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry if my correction comment was rude. But I still think this answer itself is rude for what it's worth, and the edit was justified (and has more info/keywords than plain sarcasm)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yet more evidence that the Committee is nuts. Also, you don't need to refer to `this` explicitly in the lambda- a lambda capturing `this` is effectively a member lambda as far as things like name lookup goes.

Comment: @nurettin: What's "rude" about a plain statement of fact that directly addresses the things the OP has said? Perhaps you would prefer that I sprinkle the answer with smiley faces and hashtags?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In this answer and apparently many others before this, you mock coding styles almost daily on stackoverflow as some sort of twisted repetitive ritualistic behavior. Getting a "+1" does not justify this action.

We will never come to an understanding as civilized people so long as you do not acknowledge the difference between fact and mockery.

Comment: @nurettin: Perhaps _you_ need to learn the difference between fact and mockery: it is a _fact_ that function pointers were used in the 1970s, and it is a _fact_ that `std::bind` and lambdas are both pieces of technology added to C++ in this millennium. I don't know why you've got such a problem with identifying those facts but I'll ask you to drop the ridiculous attacks: what do upvotes have to do with it? Why am I "twisted"? Where does this "almost daily" come from? (I'd love to see your _data_ and _evidence_ for that allegation).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So if I use facts to mock people, that makes it OK. Well, thanks for the lesson. I will drop all accusations and apologize for any indecent behavior.

Comment: @nurettin I'm not "mocking" anyone. By contrast you are being really quite rude to me...

Answer (score -1):

This function calculate_parameter must be static. 
Read more about function objects at
[Fuction Objects](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html)